# How to implement the publish-subscribe pattern in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, events, types, publish-subscribe

I'm working on creating an events system for my game, and my code currently looks like this:

```
export const enum ET { Collision, Dying, Damage }

type ActionCallback = (scene: Scene, event: GameEvent) => void;

subscribe(eventType: ET, callback: ActionCallback) {
  this.subscriptions[eventType].push(callback);
}
```

And then an example of some code which uses this function is like this:

```
scene.events.subscribe(ET.Dying, handleEntityDeath);

handleEntityDeath = (scene: Scene, event: DyingEvent) => {
  scene.deleteEntity(event.entity);
}
```

The problem is that TypeScript fails to compile and says something like: `event's type must be GameEvent and not DyingEvent`.

Basically, I need a way to "link" `ET.Dying` and `DyingEvent`, but I'm not sure how to do it. I think if I can accomplish this, then I can event handlers like the above where it will only compile if the first parameter is something like `ET.Dying` and the second parameter is a callback which takes a `DyingEvent`. I would want it to fail to compile if the callback instead had a `DamageEvent` parameter, if that makes sense.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: [TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/PQKhCgAIUgRBTAZgSwHbwM6QC4At6SICuqAxtsgPao4CeADgZYjvpPUQEYA2yGuhEuSqoAdFAjRIAUQAe2AE4BDcljwEA1vFpZECygFtIAA2nHISrADclvACaR4V%20Kmx1GGADQXUD9ZAMlbFJcNABzCXZ9RgVsWgs1NnolWm5KJTtxaGBwOMZIAAUuABUGeAAxVAAeaQA%20SABeSCqAaW1HeRc7LAxFcMgAMkgtWmYZWoAKKEgZpxdsAC5INtpPaZmDTAwlMPgl6QBtFYBdcABKRvqrSmQ7cHBQSRgEFHREgmIyCmp3D8oFVgEDBcDCkBTITgfITfMQSSJyRQqbDvYbaXT6IymcyWSA2eyOZyuX5eHx%20NiBYKhVARKT0aLwWLxHH%20ZKpdJ%20SiAyCkWzcTgqDSCL4iLIgHJ5AgAZRKZUqNXqTVa7XgnV8PT61MGqNGLDqUxms0Ji2W2jWBsgwGAhFQSwAslsdhVqnV1harcVQlhkhgMJhWPoiGEBP4AOSbH2OkO-HCc0TAzig8GQiYXV2IG2QCbh7a7fZHbTHC4NK43O5Fku3e6PSIvNB%20-yfYQ-CWEf5c%20OJ5D0GHc3n80gaUQyVDAhSYSL%20bOO9gpNIZSB8Cy42y3KKUGJxSBjfxzImQ-pEX2ZCTisqQe0R3ZyuqNZorDrYLrq8GaoYjMZ6qe5mT52iFy64qWVZgJExTIAQcwKLQeD9NglC7OoCiiqe%20RFJw0qcKUjDyreADerocDwfC4EsaFYU68prK6HZghCeyQBh5HXrUrokDRSb0YxsrOixAC%20wFPJAADCY5BH6SiQOgADuhRcBhC4jtgShkPA3j%20Fi0bJMomyPgC-CUEQ3AOJCFgTmeLhEJsygUJqvJckoNjINwSg8BBRpYMpZLwMgAKsnO3SipEAACKpKAY9DcPAZn5NI7l4ZEkBSUoCgZrhAQOt%20vQvmEkC8WaMCOAo%20gKEsaVfvRWX9PxUjVYJpDUL07ByVwt5oRhNTuZMqa0s1nCiIRvD8BMIZJSlIbeGVGX0QARJKhjwDBmr8g4uBKPQjDoHYACE025WcJ7gCq9D-G4jY9m1XDyimpG9eROH4a6lrcg1birb4kUKBgpWQAcIxLJV1LHEsEwXjmFF1GcBzHLleHVQaT3%20GgumoLYC7hZFmyuEEIhbiwb12B9WA8twfICull4EBKWB2JQfqoJQbgUrp3hSQQPI0N6WAhsptBRlJyB4AZbj1SpKWuiLjX44T32-do-0amEQOZqDjpyjztSQ9DvGw-c5pjtgRApZA%20HmuaA3EcDu7YN4BgYGE5bG66psGlLDIYAcVvHKIiD-NIKi4BMAjFpAAe2-b%203OzMeW65H7F0ZbRreMTpMDg7JuR%20aEtuINbhNK7n0e0a0MAPzFz9pwZ%20aOf9YeAfJ-2GgR5XMz5%207nu3jnTsGtHXczGxIK0ZCCfzEnfYCmnvem5F2d8LnIeeYThfzCXZdQ5PVezx3s-e05umBwBAhbQ0TT1%20P68uwvbtL640NNJ3Gdw1H4D8fcDxWmAH%20f1-38-7-f--3-N%200AAG-xkLIMKEUCAAEl0bwExkpHsICf5AKQagtB6Cv73BbASeYWAmjpxEvAMSdgChu2oN9W48tsreBRpsKhVVpgIGnvAEhZDUrsDYVAuw9DqQAG5ICiQwOQyAAMcr8RflnJq6EWpNAupwKoVsMBdSrO6SUIjcAGSMoVYqkBIQ8kPAQaagjqC7RppgVAIY3Aqk3j8FYDRCHENIZ9ag4BCIYRrkRIa00HGPlYc41A00JoLm4ZAEMABGcakkwr0RDPVKCkTjEZhDFGXi%200gHFDUfpQyDgGQ6L0UoAxkAjFEKEQEyAZiMAWKsbIGxNA7E%20JYU40prjepxgHhxCY3jRK%20KaSY7wWYpoT0zg1SgkVRBpDCAMimohaGqXJmDUQiT9qpPAEAA)

First, create a new file: `PubSub.ts`:

```
/**
 * Defines the function type of the publish function.
 *
 * Extracts the keys from `E` as valid event types, and the matching
 * property as the payload.
 */
type PubTypeFn<E> = <Key extends string & keyof E>(
    event: Key,
    message: E[Key]
) => void

/**
 * Defines the function type for the subscribe function.
 *
 * Extracts the keys from `E` as valid event types, and the matching
 * property as the payload to the callback function.
 */
type SubTypeFn<E> = <Key extends string & keyof E>(
    event: Key,
    fn: MessageFn<E>
) => void

/**
 * Defines the function type for the subscription callback. Ensures
 * the message payload is a valid property of the event being used.
 */
type MessageFn<E> = <Key extends string & keyof E>(message: E[Key]) => void

/**
 * Tie everything together.
 */
type PubSubType<E> = {
    publish: PubTypeFn<E>,

    subscribe: SubTypeFn<E>
    unsubscribe: SubTypeFn<E>
}

/**
 * Creates a new PubSub instance, the `E` type parameter should be a
 * type enumerating all the available events and their payloads.
 *
 * @example
 * type Events = {
 *  warn: { message: string },
 *  error: { message: string }
 * }
 *
 * const pubSub = PubSub<Events>() 
 * pubSub.publish('warn', { message: "Something bad happened!" })
 */
export function PubSub<E>(): PubSubType<E> {

    const handlers: { [key: string]: (MessageFn<E>)[] } = {}

    return {
        publish: (event, msg) => {
            handlers[event].forEach(h => h(msg))
        },

        subscribe: (event, callback) => {
            const list = handlers[event] ?? []
            list.push(callback)
            handlers[event] = list
        },

        unsubscribe: (event, callback) => {
            let list = handlers[event] ?? []
            list = list.filter(h => h !== callback)
            handlers[event] = list
        }
    }
}
```

Next, create another file where you will use the `PubSub` func:

```
import { PubSub } from './PubSub'


type events = {
  CreatedPerson: { id: string, name: string }
  DeletedPerson: { personId: string; reason: string }
}

const pubSub = PubSub<events>()

pubSub.publish("CreatedPerson", { id: '1', name: 'cory' })

pubSub.subscribe("CreatedPerson", (message) => {
    console.log(message)
})
```

> ref: https://gist.github.com/sidola/3b267f21c872e449ef4bbdae9e2baeab

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
interface EventMap {
  [ET.Collision]: CollisionEvent;
  [ET.Dying]: DyingEvent;
  // etc
}

subscribe = <T extends ET>(eventType: T, callback: (scene: Scene, event: EventMap[T]) => void) => {
  this.subscriptions[eventType].push(callback);
}

// Example calling code below here:

scene.events.subscribe(ET.Dying, handleEntityDeath);

handleEntityDeath = (scene: Scene, event: DyingEvent) => {
  scene.deleteEntity(event.entity);
}
```