# How to use an interface mapping to create a new type?

Tags: typescript, pool

Is something like this possible in Typescript?

```
const enum ET {
  Collision,
  Dying,
  Collected
}

interface EventMap {
  [ET.Collision]: CollisionEvent;
  [ET.Dying]: DyingEvent;
  [ET.Collected]: CollectedEvent;
}

class GameEvent {
  static grabFromPool(type: ET) {
    let entry = GameEvent.pool[type];

    if (entry.length === 0) {
      return new EventMap[type](); // this line is throwing the error
    } else {
      return entry.pop();
    }
  }

  private static pool: Array<Array<GameEvent>> = [ [], [], [] ];
}
```

I'm trying to create an object pool. The line I marked is giving the following error:

`'EventMap' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

I'm trying to instantiate the corresponding class (example: `CollisionEvent`) based on the given type parameter (`ET`).

Comment: That's not quite a [mcve] because I don't know what `CollisionEvent` etc are, but maybe you're looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2KbYN)... you can't use an interface at runtime; why not replace the interface with a runtime object holding the class constructors?

Comment: @jcalz things like `CollisionEvent` can basically be considered an empty class for this example.

Comment: Okay, I see I just need to remove the `interface` keyword. Unfortunately I _also_ need an interface mapping (see my previous questions for why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295113/how-to-implement-the-publish-subscribe-pattern-in-typescript) So do I just have to maintain two mappings then, or is there a way to automatically create one from the other?

Comment: you can generate your type from your const, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVnRW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `EventMap` is only a type, with no runtime value. You need a real object:

```
const EventMap = {
  [ET.Collision]: CollisionEvent,
  [ET.Dying]: DyingEvent,
  [ET.Collected]: CollectedEvent,
}
```

If you need the type:

```
type EventMap = typeof EventMap
// Inferred as this \/
{
    0: typeof CollisionEvent;
    1: typeof DyingEvent;
    2: typeof CollectedEvent;
}
```

Note that in a **type** expression, `CollisionEvent` refers to an instance of the class, and `typeof CollisionEvent` refers to the class and its constructor.

Comment: Okay cool this is good to know. Unfortunately I also need an interface mapping (explained above as to why). Is there a way to construct one automatically from the other, or do I just have to maintain both?